# In Bash, how to randomly select a file from a static list?

Tags: bash, script, linux-mint, slideshow

I have this bash script

```
while true ; do for i in * ; do cp "$i" ~/slideshow.jpg ; echo $i ; sleep 5 ; done ; done
```

How can I randomize this process?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this question is a homework assignment. Let me do it for you.

`*` in that script is likely returning an alphabetized listing of a directory. So you could intercept that listing and randomize at that point.

You could also load the directory contents in to an array, randomly pick a number - mod the array size and if the result was empty, advance forward until you hit an non-empty entry. Then empty that entry as you consume it. You'd need a counter or something to then keep track of how many elements you've used so you know when you've consumed all entries.

Further, you could instead load the entries in to something like a linked-list and come up with a random entry # to consume and then discard from the data structure.

There are likely many other options. But I just gave you sketches for 3 crude approaches. Sure I didn't write code for you, but I did the *hard* part. You're welcome ;)

Comment: No, it isn't homework. I'm an artist who's new to Linux and is need of slideshow that allows me to control the delay between images and randomize it for gesture drawings.

I copied that script from this thread http://superuser.com/a/212838/458779

I posted it here to ask for help because I'm not allowed to comment in that thread.

So, I know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The following should AFAIK work on any POSIX system.

A random ordered list of files can be obtained with:

```
for i in *; do echo "$i"; done |                              \
  awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; srand (); } { print rand (), $0 }' | \
  sort |                                                      \
  cut -f2-
```

Explanation:

- `for i in *; do echo "$i"; done` gives a list of files, one per line.
- `awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; srand (); } { print rand (), $0 }'` adds a field with a random number in [0,1) range to each line.
- `sort` sorts using that random number as index, therefore randomizing the file list.
- `cut -f2-` removes the random number field.

The original command (with copying and sleeping) can then be constructed as:

```
for i in $(for i in *; do echo "$i"; done |                              \
             awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"; srand (); } { print rand (), $0 }' | \
             sort |                                                      \
             cut -f2-);                                                  \
do                                                                       \
  cp "$i" ~/slideshow.jpg;                                               \
  echo "$i";                                                             \
  sleep 5;                                                               \
done
```

Of course you can remove backslashes and newlines if you like one-liners ;)